# When Maven expands SNAPSHOT versions to the current datetime, what does the number at the end represent?

Tags: maven

When Maven deploys an artifact with a SNAPSHOT version defined, I understand it 'expands' the SNAPSHOT qualifier with the current datetime.  For example,

```
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Might get deployed as `1.0.0-20200101-230000-1` if I deployed on 2020/01/01 at 11pm.

But I can't seem to find any information about that `-1` at the end.  Is that a build number? Why is it needed, and when does it get incremented?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This number is incremented for every build of the same SNAPSHOT version, so as long as you build `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` the number increases by one for each build.

Why it is there, I can only speculate:

1. It gives you an absolute guarantee that the generated version number is unique (I admit that builds < 1s are not very realistic...)
2. It allows you to quickly see how many SNAPSHOTS were build.